# How to keep list processing function from making duplicate operations if some list components are identical?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and am having a problem with an algorithm I am writing in python. It first assembles a list from a sequence of variables (which each contain a list), and I need it to be able to call the same variable multiple times within a sequence. It then processes the list Like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = [4, 5, 6]

c = [a, b]

def function(input):
    return output
```

so that `function(c)` returns `[[1, 2, 3, output_a1], [4,5,6, output_b1]]`

If anyone would like to know more about the function, I will gladly provide more information, but my troubleshooting this far has led me to believe that the source problem is rather simple. The problem I am having is that if I call the same variable multiple times in my master list like so: `c = [a, b, a]`, I would like `function(c)` to return:

```
[[1, 2, 3, output_a1],
[4, 5, 6, output_b1],
[1, 2, 3, output_a2]]
```

However, `function()` processes all instances of `a` when it encounters just one, so that I get:

```
[[1, 2, 3, output_a1, output_a3],
[4, 5, 6, output_b1],
[1, 2, 3, output_a1, output_a3]]
```

I have found two ways to fix this, but I am really not happy with them and I suspect there is a better way. In the first way, I print `c` and copy and paste it into the function:

```
function_a([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]])
```

and this returns the desired output. Additionaly, I can create another variable with the same contents as `a`, `d = [1, 2, 3]`, and have `c = [a, b, d]`, and once again, `function_a(c)` will return the desired output. I have tried a variety of things, but it seems that if any element in `c` is linked to another through variables, then I encounter this error. Since I will be running this algorithm with fairly lengthy sequences that may contain several instances of the same element, I would really like a clean way to fix this error. Any advice is much appreciated, and I will provide more details about the function if need be. Thanks for reading!

Comment: What does `function` do? Can you show us the source of the function?

Comment: Superb first question ;) Way to go!

Comment: There is only *one* instance of the list. `a` just points to the object. When you mutate `a`, you mutate the original list, so all variables pointing to it "get modified". Your function will need to work on copies of the lists.

Comment: You must be probably appending `output_ax` to list `a` or to something like `local_a = a`. If this is the case remember that in Python, if you don't take the necessary steps to do at least a shallow copy of that list, you're going to modify the original list.  
See if this helps: http://www.bioruffo.net/lpotf/bindings-shallow-copy-deep-copy/115

Comment: You need to write `function` to be a *pure* function - i.e. one without side effects.  Without seeing it, I'd bet that your `function` mutates the input lists.

Comment: Thank you very much Roberto! Calling deep copies of each variable was exactly what I needed to do, and I learned quite a bit from the page you linked. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is reading this with the same problem, Roberto responded with [this link](http://www.bioruffo.net/lpotf/bindings-shallow-copy-deep-copy/115) which provided all the information I needed to solve the problem. Little did I know, if I am working with a nested list that contains multiple copies from the same variable, I need to make a deep copy of it to prevent any part of the list from being modified.